# How to see users' idle time on RDP server

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a quick and easy way to see users' session idle time on an RDP server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal Services Manager can get you this information.

Under administrative tools -> Terminal Services -> Terminal Services Manager

Then select the host in the left pane and in the middle pane select the "Sessions" tab. There will be a listing of all active sessions and there is an "IdleTime" column.

The output is intererpeted as "Days+Hours:minutes". So for example, if the output is "4+11:23" the user has been idle for 4 days, 11 hours, and 23 minutes.

It's also worth noting that you can log these sessions off by right clicking and disconnecting them. Though it might be nice to pay them a phone call first :P

**Edit**: Well that's a good answer for versions of Server prior to 2012 :( But since they eliminated Terminal Services Manager from newer versions of Server, it seems like this powershell script might be the best option: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LoggedOnUser-Gathers-7cbe93ea

I assume that the IdleTime is being reported in minutes, since my initial tests only display single integers.

Comment: I like your thinking, and I really miss Terminal Services Manager, but as far as I know, the tool no longer exists :(This is Server 2012 R2)

Comment: This is still possible in Server 2012 R2.

Server Manager --> Remote Desktop Services --> Collections (RDS hosts need to be in the pool).
Review connections in the bottom right panel.
Time seems to be hours : minutes : seconds

Comment: Oh good to know!

Answer (score 9):

Since Windows 2008 the command [quser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754583(v=ws.11).aspx) works.

> Displays information about user sessions on a Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server.

In fact, the PowerShell script linked to in answer simply runs this command. OP asked for a quick and easy way, this is definitively quicker than to download and execute PS-script.

Example from Windows Server 2012 R2:

```
C:\Users\admin.tedd>quser
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 admin.xxxxxxxx                            2  Disc     15+15:12  7/20/2017 1:19 PM
 admin.xxxxx           rdp-tcp#54          3  Active       1:39  7/21/2017 5:35 AM
 xxxxxxxx                                  4  Disc      6+04:10  7/21/2017 9:25 AM
>admin.tedd            rdp-tcp#86          5  Active          .  8/9/2017 4:40 PM
```

Number in front of + is days, so 15+15:12 is 15 days, 15 hours and 12 minutes.

Note! Documentation says this is the same as running `query user`. The command `query` does not exist on my servers. Not sure if this is separate install or part of a feature install.

Comment: `query user` and `quser` have the same output on my Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

in command prompt (CMD) just type:

query user

Then it will show you the result.

Comment: `query user` "
'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: "query user" worked for me in powershell window on the server (Windows 2012 R2)

Comment: `query user` and `quser` have the same output on my Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score -1):

You can use powershell to locate various users or multiple server's idle time
The script was created by user "Cookie.Monster" on technet
[Get-UserSession - Parse query user result](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-UserSessions-Parse-b4c97837)

More detail of the script, and usage can be found in the link above

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-RDUserSession |ft Username,Idletime
Get-RDUserSession |select-object UserName,Servername,IdleTime,CreateTime
```

Just a few examples – the BIG issue is converting the "idletime property"  which is some integer of time Example: 6667354 converted to Days:HH:MM:SS

I have not figured that out yet.

Comment: Where? (Power)shell?

Comment: If someone else would be interested, the `IdleTime` property returned by `Get-RDUserSession` command is in milliseconds and you can convert it to a more readable format using the function `[TimeSpan]::FromMilliseconds()`.